# In-text citations for a source with no page numbers

Tags: citations, essay, mla

I'm using online sources for an essay for my DE History course, and we're required to use in-text citations when we quote or paraphrase sources, with the format of author-page number, like (Johnson 12).  But the online articles that I'm citing don't exactly have tangible pages, so do I just use (Author) and leave off the page number, or something else?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The answer is two fold:

1. Ask your teacher.
2. Google it.

I can't ask your teacher for you, but I did a quick Google search.  Since you added the [mla](/questions/tagged/mla) tag, I assume that's the format required.  So here's the official word:

> ## Citing non-print or sources from the Internet
>
>
>   With more and more scholarly work being posted on the Internet, you may have to cite research you have completed in virtual environments.
>   While many sources on the Internet should not be used for scholarly
>   work (reference the OWL's Evaluating Sources of Information resource),
>   some Web sources are perfectly acceptable for research. When creating
>   in-text citations for electronic, film, or Internet sources, remember
>   that your citation must reference the source in your Works Cited.
>
> Sometimes writers are confused with how to craft parenthetical
>   citations for electronic sources because of the absence of page
>   numbers, but often, these sorts of entries do not require a page
>   number in the parenthetical citation. For electronic and Internet
>   sources, follow the following guidelines:
>
> - Include in the text the first item that appears in the Work Cited entry that corresponds to the citation (e.g. author name, article
>     name, website name, film name).
> - You do not need to give paragraph numbers or page numbers based on your Web browser’s print preview function.
> - Unless you must list the Web site name in the signal phrase in order to get the reader to the appropriate entry, do not include URLs
>     in-text. Only provide partial URLs such as when the name of the site
>     includes, for example, a domain name, like CNN.com or Forbes.com as
>     opposed to writing out http://www.cnn.com or http://www.forbes.com.

Comment: Also, make sure that the links provided look like they are going to be there for some time.

Comment: yes, you can copy the link to web.archive.org 's Wayback Machine for a static copy.